# Why am I getting a Kernel size error for a CNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train the below 5 layer CNN model on images of size 64x64, however I keep getting the following Kernel size error, I tried adjusting the kernel size but the same error comes back.

```
CNN5Layers = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=512 * 8 * 8, out_features=1024),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=30)
)
```

The error message: **Calculated padded input size per channel: (2 x 2). Kernel size: (3 x 3). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size**

I initially started with a model of 3 CNN layers which was working fine however when adding more layers this error appeared.

Anyone got a clue what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Are you aware that convolution and pooling reduce feature map size?

Comment: Does this imply that I must increase the number of features the more convolution layers I add?

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @crazyProudCoder what Dr. Snoopy is trying to tell you is that the error message is quite self-explanatory, in the sense that you reach a point where the input channel dimension is 2x2 and despite that you want to add a filter of 3x3 which is of course bigger than the size of the input channel.

Comment: Well I am asking about understanding, because with that the error becomes quite more clear, but more importantly, what can be the solution.

Comment: I think I get it now, I would have to add padding to fix it